# is there an equivalent to jsfiddle for android layouts?

Tags: xml, android-layout, xml-parsing, jsfiddle

jsfiddle (and its brethren) are great for proof-of-concepting HTML/CSS/jQuery; what about something similar for Android Layout (xml) files?

It would be awesome to paste something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/id"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/pack_size"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPackSize"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25" />

</LinearLayout>
```

...into such a tool, and immediately receive visual feedback of what it represents. I searched for such a beast, but found nothing. Is anybody aware of such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are requesting is already supported with ADT Bundle and Android Studio.

If you are looking for online solution, here is what I found:

[DroidDraw](https://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/) which is WYSIWYG User Interface for Android

It requires Java.

There is also a standalone versions for this application.